# Bounty Link is set to Black

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

I am not sure if this was intended and at least in my opinion should be blue. It's to do with the style applied if you remove the color parameter from the CSS link, the problem is resolved :)

Current:

```
a.bounty-link {
    padding: 0 3px 2px;
    color: #0C0D0E
}
```

After:

```
a.bounty-link {
    padding: 0 3px 2px
}
```

You can see the issue here:

*[Is there any viable alternative of MiniProfiler for .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789912/is-there-any-viable-alternative-of-miniprofiler-for-net-core)*

Comment: Do you say the color of the link becomes black while clicking the Link?, Is that your question?

Comment: @A.Sakkeer to me, the color of 'start a bounty' link is black in the first place, while 'add a comment' above it is blue.

Comment: As Andrew.T said :)

Comment: Be careful with the questions you bring up on Meta. That question is off-topic, as it is asking us to find a tool for them.

Comment: Current styles for `a.bounty-link` do not set the color.